# how to make ubuntu software center know about my debian file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, installation

I created a debian installation file for my software and now i want to publish it. Primarily I want a user install my software by going to Ubuntu Software Center typing a few search keywords and it would display my installation as one of the search results. Then user would click install and software would install. How do i achieve that??

I looked through answers and some docs but they are very vague and long. I know it has to be easy step-by-step somewhere. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, Debian and Ubuntu repos go by PPA, so you can create a repo with aptly or similar and have people add your PPA repo. Or you can request your package to be added to their main repo.

Comment: this is not what i am looking for. PPA require source code to be uploaded. My source code is private and I only want users to search for my software in Ubuntu Software center and then be able to install it from deb file which i prepared.